# How can I set up networking under Basilisk II / MacOS 8.7?

Tags: networking, macos

How can I enable networking under Basilisk? So far, none of the permutations I've tried have allowed iCab to load any site, including google.com.

Thanks,

[image: screenshot of Basilisk II Network settings]